# VB: Instantiate object before Timer tick and use the same object on every tick

Tags: vb.net, timer

So I am trying to write a basic ticker application for getting price information from the internet. I have decided to do this in visual basic as I have some knowledge of VBA and a free copy of Visual Studio.

Currently, I have a Form Module which has a timer object. On each tick (1 second interval), I call a function (that is in a separate module) that tries to get the data from the API. This is done by sending POST to the HTTP address and requires creating a MSXML.XMLHTTP object. I also need to create another object for hashing some of the signatures I send and a ScriptControl object to parse the JSON response.

My question is, it is bad that these objects are instantiated on every tick? Is it possible to write my code such that the objects are instantiated when say I press an ON button, and the pull functions use these existing objects on each tick? If so, how can access these objects?

EDIT: Here is a brief outline of how I think my code should look:

In Form1.vb I have:

```
    Imports System.Net
    Imports System.Text
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Class Form1

    Public Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
       Application.DoEvents()

       ' I would like to pass the oXMLHTTP object here so that i can use it in the getPrice() function below, use it in there to send POST requests
       Dim ticker_API As String = "https://example.com/api/"
       Me.PriceBox.Text = getPrice(ticker_API)

    End Sub

    ' on button starts timer
    Public Sub OnButton_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OnButton.Click
        ' start execution...
        Timer1.Enabled = True

       ' I would like to instantiate the object here and use it by the getPrice() function
       Dim oXMLHTTP As Object
       oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    End Sub

End Class
```

In Module1.vb I have the getPrice() function:

```
Module Module1

function getPrice(byval postURL as string, byval oXMLHTTP as object) as string
       Dim argumentString as String

       With oXMLHTTP
            .Open("POST", postURL, False)
            .setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.0)")
            .setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .send(argumentString)
            Return .responseText
        End With

End Function

End Module
```

Thanks and please let me know if any additional information is required to answer the question.

EDIT: I would like to make multiple data-pulling function calls at each interval.

Armen

Comment: vba and vb.net are different.

Comment: I personally prefer to see some code. Don't need to post everything; just the relevant bits, like the connection and timer parts. If you have to refer variables/methods which you don't include, please, write down a small description of what they do.

Comment: `Is it possible to write my code such that the objects are instantiated when say I press an ON button` yes, but the devil is in the details - show the Timer.Tick code

Comment: Hi, I have added some code now.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a new `MSXML.XMLHTTP` object for each call.

But the object you use to send the POST, the object that stores you hashed signatures, and your ScriptControl can all likely be re-used.

Whether it's bad or not that you re-create these on each tick remains to be seen. You can't know until you measure you current performance relative to some metric, such that you know whether or not you're meeting performance goals.

Comment: The object I use to send the post is MSXML.XMLHTTP

Comment: Since you're getting back JSON, rather than html, you might consider System.Net.WebClient or System.Net.HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse instead, then.

Comment: Thanks I will check these out, I initially started writing the program in VBA and i could only get XMLHTTP to work. How can I pass the other objects to the functions?  Additionally, I want to make multiple function calls that pull different data from different API at each interval.